# What is pythonic way to do dt[,y:=myfun(x),by=list(a,b,c)] in R?

Tags: python, r, pandas

Suppose I have a data frame which have column `x, a, b, c` And I would like to aggregate over `a, b, c` to get a value y from a list of x via a function `myfun`, then duplicate the value for all rows within each window/partition.

In R in `data.table` this is just 1 line:  `dt[,y:=myfun(x),by=list(a,b,c)]`.

In Python the only way I think of is do something like this:

```
 # To simulate rows in a data frame
 class Record:
      def __init__(self, x, a, b, c):
           self.x = x
           self.a = a
           self.b = b
           self.c = c

 # Assume we have a list of Record as df
 mykey = attrgetter('a', 'b', 'c')
 for key, group_iter in itertools.groupby(sorted(df, key=mykey), key=mykey):
     group = list(group_iter)
     y = myfun(x.x for x in group)
     for x in group:
         x.y = y
```

Although the logic is quite clear, I am not 100% happy with it. Is there any better approach?

I am not very familiar with `pandas`. Does it help in such case?

Side question: is there a category that my problem belongs to? aggregation? partition? window? This pattern happens so frequently in data analysis, there must be an existing name for it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a `DataFrame` and its `groupby` method from `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['x', 'y', 'x', 'y'],
                   'x': [1, 2, 3, 4]})

df.groupby('a').apply(myfun)
```

The exact usage depends on how you wrote your function `myfun`.  Where the column used is static (e.g. always `x`) I write `myfun` to take the full `DataFrame` and subset inside the function.  However if your function is written to accept a vector (or a pandas `Series`), you can also select the column and `apply` your function to it:

```
df.groupby('a')['x'].apply(myfun)
```

FWIW, it is also often convenient to return a `pd.Series` object when you're using `groupby`.

---

To answer your side question, this is known as the split-apply-combine strategy of data processing.  See [here](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i01/) for more info.

Comment: @agstudy While there is a bit of overhead compared to raw numpy, the convenience is hard to beat!  It also has some really pleasant plotting features (like `df.plot()`) that significantly lower the bar for data exploration in python

Comment: thanks. I tried d.plot() with your example but it doesn't work ( looks like he want a numeric vectors..no implicit coercion). I will see deeper.

Comment: @agstudy I didn't mean my example would work, however, it should plot a line where x-axis is the index (1,2,3..) and y-axis is the `x` column.

Comment: What are the advantages of python (ipython, pandas, ...) over R? Speed (data.table is great...)? memory usage? Is it worth to switch or at least know both?